# ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./src/assets Module not found

Tags: angular, module

i am trying to make my angular web app. It is working fine and suddenly this error came without doing any changing in my file. i don't know how to remove this error. So help me please to remove this error.

> ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./src/assets Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\demoapp\blog\src\assets' in 'D:\demoapp\blog'

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4778  this might be useful

Comment: Please check any changes happend in angular.json? i